# Format errors in Stack Exchange syntax?

Tags: support, comments, chat, formatting

I first noticed in a chat message I sent yesterday but now it's more irritatingly present in a comment: something's up with formatting on messages? There's also a question I read today (perhaps elsewhere on the meta) where a user attempted to input italics but it would not let them.

`[Link](rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)` is correct, yes? Yet when I tried that moments ago it only spat out the code. No link :(

Comment: `[link text](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour]`. Though in comments, `[tour]` works too (similarly, `[help]`, `[chat]`, and `[edit]`: [tour], [help], [chat], [edit].

Comment: Oh bah! `[tour]` doesn't actually work. I'll raise that.

Comment: Use `[about]` instead: [about]. Ref: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3302/939.

Comment: k. [about] testing... Sweet!

Comment: _"There's also a question I read today (perhaps elsewhere on the meta) where a user attempted to input italics but it would not let them."_ Link please? *Italics work fine*, so they probably did something goofy, but it's impossible to know what.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-do-we-get-more-questions-about-things-besides-dd-4e/800#comment1812_891

Comment: @LitheOhm Without knowing what happened exactly we can't really tell what they did wrong, unfortunately. Italics themselves are working fine in general.

Answer (score 8):

In chat, sticky returns (manual line breaks to make a second paragraph in the same chat entry) break most code.

And all links need http:// or they won't process as links at all.

Answer (score 4):

> `[Link](rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)` is correct, yes?

No, it's not. You need a `http://` in there: `[Link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)`

- Broken version (no http): Link
- Working version (with http): [Link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)

### This won't work in a chat message with a line break in it

Any chat message with a line break in it becomes special in a couple of ways:

1. They contain a *much higher* character limit than normal.
2. Markdown doesn't work in them.

(There may also be other ways I'm not aware of.)

The exception to #2 seems to be the inclusion of a quote mark (`>`) at the beginning of your message, which turns the whole thing into a quote.

Message replies (`:0123457689`) and user pings (@LitheOhm) still work since they're not part of markdown.